# Koa-cookie not fetching "=" in value?

Tags: node.js, koa

We are having some issues fetching cookie values using Koa & Koa-cookie when these values contain an equal sign as part of their value. This value is a Base64 encoded string that ends with a equal sign.

The rest of the value is being fetched without problem, but the trailing equal signs are being omitted.

Is there any way to reconfigure this (not at all mentioned in the documentation), or alternative cookie-parsers that we can use to solve this issue?

Comment: Not an answer, but note that the trailing `=` characters in base64 are often not required by base64 parsers. Typically removing them does not hurt. It's basically padding to ensure that the number of characters in a base64 string are a multiple of 4.